# How to make nmap consult arp table

Tags: nmap, arp

I want to use `nmap` in a subnet with the following command:

`nmap -T3 -F 192.168.1.0/24`

My net has some interferences that make broadcast packets to be lost, so I add to my arp table the mac and ip to avoid sending arp requests, but nmap doesn't consult the arp table.

Does it exist any way to make nmap consult arp table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nmap doesn't currently have a way to query the ARP table directly, but you can still use it manually.

First, extract the IP addresses from the ARP table with the `arp` command:

```
arp -n | awk '$2=="ether"{print $1}' > ips.txt
```

Next, run Nmap, forcing it to scan regardless of ARP responsiveness:

```
nmap -iL ips.txt -Pn --disable-arp-ping
```

You can add whatever other options you like to the end of this command.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will looking for other tool that allow as I want or a workaround of this. Thank you for your help @bosaiviking